# How to create associative table where one of the fields is not primary key?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am structuring a postgres database.

I have two tables, products (coke) and optional (with ice, lemon ...), that is, a relationship many to many.

An associative table is usually built using the primary keys of the tables, correct? However, in my case, there is a specific feature ... due to some imports from other databases...I have two ids fields (id and "externalId"), one primary key and one common ... one is the local id of my bank and the other represents the id that the item has in the bank from which it was imported.

I need an associative table between "externalId" and a primary key from another table.

ExternalId is not a primary key...

```
ALTER TABLE public.opcional_produto
Add 
CONSTRAINT idproduto_fkey FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES public.produto (prod_idExt)
```

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
>   referenced table "produto" SQL state: 42830

How can I do?

Comment: Please include the table designs for all three tables: products, options and `opcional_produto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `externalid` is unique, you should create a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE produto ADD UNIQUE (externalid);
```

Ideally it should also be not nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE produto ALTER externalid SET NOT NULL;
```

Now it can be used as target of a foreign key.